# How to fix “No Module name pyspark” from exe

Tags: python, pyspark, spyder

I have created a program in Pyspark/python using spyder IDE.
Program is using Pyspark library and it runs perfectly file when i am running it from IDE SPYDER.

I created exe of same program using pyinstaller.
When i run exe from command prompt it gives error “No module name Pyspark”.

Please help/suggest.

Thank You.

I have created a program in Pyspark/python using spyder IDE.
Program is using Pyspark library and it runs perfectly file when i am running it from IDE SPYDER.

I created exe of same program using pyinstaller.
When i run exe from command prompt it gives error “No module name Pyspark

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed it with pip? `pip install pyspark` Must be install 'global' not only in your enviroment if you have one.

Comment: Yes thats why it works when running program in IDE. Like other libraries gets bundled into exe this doesn’t.

Comment: So, try add option pyinstaller --hidden-import=pyspark your_file.py

Comment: Tried this now but still getting same error.

Comment: Hmm... strange behavior. Maybe reinstalling the "pyspark" and "pyinstaller" packages will solve the problem? After reinstalling, restart your machine.

Comment: Yeah already tried that…not sure how we can fix this. I was expecting the way other libraries gets bundled into exe this should also be there but that’s not the case